# How to install ncurses on raspberry Pi?

Tags: terminal, ncurses, raspberry-pi2

How can I install the ncurses library on a raspberry Pi through the terminal?

Is there a sudo function that can be used to install it?

Comment: Are you running Raspbian? If so `apt-get` is the package manager. If using a RedHat variant like Fedora, then use `yum`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To install the NCurses library on a Debian based machine you can issue the `apt-get` command below:

```
sudo apt-get install libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev
```

This will install both the `libncurses5-dev` (for ncurses) and `libncursesw5-dev` (for ncursesw) on your machine.